# Method for calculating the time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

While being somewhat familiar with intuitively determining the complexity of algorithms, I'm a bit lost on how to actually calculate it.

For the following code, any idea how I could determine the complexity?

```
list = [...]
start = list[0]
end = null 
remove list[0] from list

while(list.length > 0) {
  for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i] is immediately before start or immediately after end) {
       link list[i] to start or end (populate end if null)
       remove list[i] from list
    } 
  }
}
```

This assumes a valid dataset (a continuously linked list of elements that must be sorted). Also was simplified for illustration purposes;

So, best case scenario it's O(n) if the list is already ordered since you'd only need a pass to process them and pop them out.

What I can't determine is the worst case scenario, since every "while" iteration the dataset is going to get smaller by at least 1 element (usually 2 or more) since it's assumed the dataset will always be valid. So it's clearly less than O(n^2) (i think). All ideas are welcomed.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
After graphing it out, it seems to be O(nlogk(n)) where k = n ^ (2/(n+1))
Does this count as O(nlog(n))? It's unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big O notation aims to provide an upper bound for the growth rate of a function, so you have to account for the worst case scenario.

In the worst case scenario I would assume in each iteration the dataset will get smaller by 1 element so the number of operations you'd be performing would be bound by `n + n-1 + n-2 ... + 2 + 1` which equals `(n+1)*n / 2` which is O(n^2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but (n * (n+1)) / 2 != n^2 unless n = 0 or 1 which would not be an intended dataset for this.  How is that equivalence reached? I'd assume n^2 would be equivalent to the dataset not getting smaller each iteration.

Comment: You can't compare the results of these calculations themselves, just their order for O comparison. `(n²+n)/2` is bounded by the `n²` factor, and thus it is indeed O(n²). What big O notation says is how the time the algorithm takes to run scaled with the input it receives, and in this case it is quadratically even though the constants are < 1.